# Regex to replace characters between numbers in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
add = '$4.545,45 is less than $5,454.54.'
```

This command :

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\d).(?=\d{1,})',',',add)
```

results in

```
'$4,5,5,45 is less than $5,4,4,54.'
```

but

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\d).(?=\d{2,})',',',add)
```

results in

```
'$4,545,45 is less than $5,454,54.'
```

Second one is correct, Both means convert the one that has digitbefore then full stop then digit , then why {1,} gives weird result.

I checked https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html as well but still confused.

Also, is there any other way to solve this as well.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/dC25gH/1 vs. https://regex101.com/r/dC25gH/2. Always escape special chars in the regex pattern if they must be treated as literal chars.

Comment: Thank you Wikton!